# Mercurial merging mechanism

Tags: merge, mercurial, version

I'm just starting to work with Mercurial, using the GUI provided with the Eclipse plug-in.

I've read on one of the tutorials about Mercurial that:

> In Mercurial merges are always managed on local repositories.

When I make a push operation and it needs to be managed as a merge on the
remote repo, Mercurial manages my push under the hood automatically merging the remote repo wit my local repo, is that correct?

This would mean that automatically managed merges can take place on the remote repo.

Furthermore At this point my local repo would not still be in sync with the rempote repo and another merge operation would be needed locally.

Please tell me what is that I'm missing here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mercurial does not create new commits when pushing.  Since merging normally does create new commits, pushing will not automatically merge anything.  Instead, it checks to see whether merging is necessary, that is, whether you are creating a new head by pushing.

If pushing would create a new head, you will get an error which tells you to pull and merge first.  You can override that with `hg push --force`, but this is *normally* the wrong thing to do, because then the heads will not get merged at all.

Comment: so basically it is correct that mercurial manages all the merge operation in local repositories and my understanding of push was somehow flawed ?

Comment: Push and pull are very simple operations.  They copy commits around (from one repo to another).  They do not do anything else.  Note that this is quite different from git, where pull does an automatic merge.

Comment: in mercurial when pulling can automatic merges occur  on the local repo?

Comment: **No**.  Pulling does one thing: it copies commits from repo A into repo B.  The same is true of pushing, just in reverse.  (Technically, pushing also affects [phases](https://selenic.com/hg/help/phases), while pulling normally does not, but most of the time you don't need to care about phases anyway.)

Comment: so when do automatic merges occur in mercurial ?

Comment: For the most part, they don't.  There are some operations like rebase and shelve which use merge logic behind the scenes (mostly to implement "moving" changesets from one part of history to another), and of course you can always merge manually, but none of Mercurial's basic operations (update, commit, push, pull, merge) will merge things automatically, with the obvious exception of merge itself.